# difference between req.getsession().getservletcontext() and getservletcontext()

Tags: java, servlets

I have seen that you can call getservletcontext() directly also and also like this  req.getsession().getservletcontext() .

What is the difference between the two and which one should I use ? Is there any scenario based on which I should use one and not the other?

And by the way I am using web module 2.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two

There is no difference between the two, they are one and the same.

The method `getServletContext()` that you can call directly is only when your code is in a class that extends `HttpServlet`. That is because `HttpServlet` base class has this method defined (actually in the `GenericServlet` class that `HttpServlet` extends).

The `ServletContext` returned by req.getSession().getServletContext()`is same as the one  returned above.`HttpSession`contains a reference to the`ServletContext` that this session belongs to.

> which one should I use?  Is there any scenario based on which I should use one and not the other?

As long as your code is in the servlet class, you can use anything as both can be called.

Let's say (hypothetically) you call a method in your custom class from your servlet and pass the session object to it to work on some data in the session. This custom class doesn't extend servlet. You need a reference to the `ServletContext` in this custom class. Since you have a reference to the session, you can get access to the ServletContext using the method `session.getServletContext()`.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: I am a noob ..can you please break down your answer a little for me so that i can understand :(   ....maybe with an example

Comment: actually i didn't get the part where you said " to be used at places outside the HttpServlet class."

Comment: @Nav, I tried to elaborate on my answer. Please see the edit.

Answer (score -1):

The **Session** variables are only saved for one browser and the **Context** variables can be used by all browsers in one session.

So if the user only uses one browser (as it is in most cases) there is no difference between them, but if you like to work from different browsers in one session better use the **Context**.